# Long polling using jQuery in Rails with turbolink

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, polling, turbolinks

I am following an instruction to create long polling using jQuery AJAX request [here](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery). 
Below is my code:

```
:javascript
  (function poll(){
      $.ajax({ url: $("comment").data("url"), success: function(data){
          alert(data.comment);
      }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 8000 });
  })();
```

But instead of timeout for 8 seconds, this code polls continuously. Am I doing something wrong, or does this somehow conflict with `turbolink` gem that I am using with Rails 3.2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why it polls again because you are calling the function poll again in the complete callback

```
    (function poll(){
          $.ajax({ url: $("comment").data("url"), success: function(data){
              alert(data.comment);
          }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 8000 });
-----------------------------------------^ //here
      })();
```

also dont confuse the `timeout` with `setTimeout`, here timeout means that if the ajax call does not return within 8 seconds it will trigger the error call back

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D6JXX/1/)